# Error using Clang while compiling on Mac OS

Tags: macos, clang

I'm using clang++ to compile a project related to some libraries. When compiling, I'm getting such errors :

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:316:9: error: no member 
named 'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
  ~~^
```

or

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:552:28: error: expected 
a qualified name after 'typename'
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR typename enable_if<is_floating_point<_A1>::value, bool>::type
                       ^
```

My clang version is :

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include- 
dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/anas@MacBook-Pro-de-Anas src %
```

I don't know why I'm getting these errors since I upgrade to Mac Os Catalina.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What command did you use which generated these errors?

Comment: I used this command :  clang++ -w  -c main.cpp   -I /usr/local/include -I trimesh2/include/ -I armadillo-6.400.3/include/ -I /usr/X11R6/include  -I /Users/anass/project/include  -o main.o

Comment: If you are on a Mac using XQuartz, that is normally installed in `/opt/X11` so you would want `-I /opt/X11/include`

Comment: You should probably also specify which standard you are using, e.g. `-std=c++11` or somesuch.

Comment: I changed the path to X11 using -I /opt/X11/include but I've got the same errors. Also, nothing have changed when adding c++11 flag since I'm using "normal" C++